# Water pressure in sink is low after plumber came to fix shower water pressure

Tags: shower, sink, water-pressure, kitchen-sink

We had low water pressure in our showers.

Plumber came the first time, replaced the water pressure regulator. This did not fix the issue.

Plumber came the second time. Turns out we had 2 water pressure regulators. He removed the second one. I don't know why. The pressure in the showers seems to be "okay" now. But now there is a new problem, which is that our kitchen sink now has low water pressure (like half of what it was before he came).

What is going on and what can I do?

Comment: you had 2 regulators, one for kitchen one for the rest of the home

Comment: If the original problem and the reason you called a plumber was low water pressure, call the plumber back.  This time check pressure at all devices prior to the plumber leaving.

Comment: Have you considered that this may simply be caused by debris from the work that was done? Disassemble the kitchen faucet spout/aerator/sprayer and check for debris.